# Matrix column mirror like rearrange in C

Tags: c, matrix

I have to first insert the number of rows and columns, then the elements and show the whole matrix. After that to arrange the columns in a mirror like way. For example:
If the matrix has one row and 5 columns, it should look like this:

Matrix 1 2 3 4 5 should become 5 4 3 2 1

The same thing goes for more than one row.

This is what I did so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main()
{
    int m, n, i, j, matrix[10][10];
    printf("Insert the number of rows and columns:\n");
    scanf("%d%d", &m, &n);
    printf("Insert the desired elements:\n");
    for (i = 0; i < m; i++)
        for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
            scanf("%d", &matrix[i][j]);
    printf("Your matrix has the following elements:\n");
    for (i = 0; i < m; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0 ; j < n; j++)
        {
            printf("%d\t", matrix[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

If there is a better way, or I did something wrong, please tell me.

SOLVED
Added the following:

```
printf("Your new matrix has the following elements:\n");
for (i = m-1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        for (j = n-1 ; j >= 0; j--)
    {
        printf("%d\t", matrix[i][j]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    }
```

Thanks to Jonathan Leffler for the idea.

Comment: Your question says C#, but that looks like C or C++ code

Comment: Sorry...i edited it.

Comment: In case you wonder about the downvotes: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10811/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions Also, codereview.stackexchange.com is certainly a better place for you to ask. This site is about fixing bugs.

Comment: You've got a moderately good start; now you need to show your code to print the data in reverse order — presumably by counting down instead of counting up, at least in the inner loop and possibly in both loops.  Your data entry code should check that `scanf()` succeeded each time, and you should check that neither `m` nor `n` is bigger than 10 (or less than 1, but that is less dangerous.  **Bug**: you are counting 1..m but in C, array indexes go 0..m-1.

Comment: Thanks for the idea. I did it as you suggested (printing backwards) and it works. I also changed it to go from 0 to m-1 and n-1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<sup>*Transferring comment to answer.*</sup>

You've got a moderately good start; now you need to show your code to print the data in reverse order — presumably by counting down instead of counting up, at least in the inner loop and possibly in both loops.

Your data entry code should check that `scanf()` succeeds each time, and you should check that neither `m` nor `n` is bigger than 10 (or less than 1, but that is less dangerous; you simply won't do anything in the relevant loop).

**Bug**: you are counting 1..m and 1..n, but in C, array indexes go 0..m-1 and 0..n-1.